# Reusable Code in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, refactoring, reusability

I built two controllers which actually use some common code. So I want to refactor it in an own file. But because I am using models in this code I'm not able to use components. Is there another good solution for that? Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you thought about putting the code in AppController ?

Comment: "But because i am using models in this code" => you can work with models in components, as well.

Comment: AppController would be an oppertunity, but every controller would inherit the code, also controllers which don't need that. I tried to build a component but it doens't work like in a controller with models.

Comment: You can use `ClassRegistry::init('ModelName')` to access your desired model from the components. It breaks the MVC pattern, but if you watch the source code of cake you will see it often. You can also use it directly to do searches: `ClassRegistry::init('ModelName')->find('first');` or any other model method.

Comment: Question is a bit vague. Would help if we knew what the code is doing (data/redirects/etc).